# Angularjs - Passing the $scope to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

In Angular's online free course, I see this:

```
app.controller('GalleryController', function(){
  this.current = 0;
  this.setCurrent = function(imageNumber){
    this.current = imageNumber || 0;
  };
});
```

but usually the `$scope` is passed as an argument to the controller... so, is it really needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new "controller as" syntax. Check here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you want to use it inside your controller or not. Since in your controller you are not using $scope, you don't need to pass it as an argument to the controller.

Comment: I'm affraid that is not the case. The current prop and the setCurrent method work as if they were defined on $scope. So it is not a metter of needing it or not. Thanks anyway.